# Auto-numbering for Google Chrome download stops at 100

Tags: google-chrome

Downloading same file multiple times auto-numbers the file name from 1 to 100. After 100 it opens the `Save As` Dialog.

Is there any way to continue the auto-numbering beyond 100?

Comment: By what means? As a user? As a client-side developer? As a server-side developer?

Comment: As a user. I have a pdf generated with filename report. After I reached the download of report(100).pdf, it has started giving me the `Save As` dialog box.

Comment: This behavior is intentional. If you're willing to, then you could create an extension that renames the file with a number that keeps incrementing.

Comment: Any idea how can I stop this!

Comment: @Reema - Did you find a solution for this issue?

Comment: No! Living with it, as it hardly happens

Comment: @sll - Follow this [link](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=135428#c26) Hopefully they are planning to sort it soon. – Reema 1 hour ago

Comment: As of today, it does not open the `Save As` dialog but appends a timestamp to the filename, which is much better in my opinion. In fact it should do that from the second file onwards, instead of appending `(1)`, `(2)`, etc

Answer (score 3):

***Edit: As of Jan 29 2019 this was fixed and you can download more than 100 files and have the auto-numbering continue to function!***

Currently this is marked as WontFix on the Chrome developer bug tracker: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=135428

It was raised five years ago (at the time of writing) but there have been votes to fix it since then.

If you want it fixed, please don't reply to that bug, but login using your Google account and "star" it (click the star icon, top left). That will vote for a fix.